# Add a list to the file in ansible

Tags: ansible

I have this list.

```
provider:
  name: prov1
  ip_list:
    - 1.2.3.4
    - 4.5.6.7
    - 7.8.9.10
```

I want add this list to config file, What I need:

File config:

```
dbr:excludeRange({"1.2.3.4"}) -- prov1
dbr:excludeRange({"4.5.6.7"}) -- prov1
dbr:excludeRange({"7.8.9.10"}) -- prov1
```

I checked different `loop`, `dict` and etc of the ansible but I still have not reached the desired.
result.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This example will only work with the list you show there, if you want to work with multiple items, or multiple providers, you should provide a better var/list example but maybe this can help you, this example works using jinja expressions (Also i had to escape the characters '{' and '}' so they will appear in your file):

```
- name: create list
  lineinfile:
    line: "{% for ip in provider.ip_list %}dbr:excludeRange({{'{'}}{{ip}}{{'}'}}) -- {{provider.name}}\n{% endfor %}"
    dest: /tmp/list.txt
    create: yes
```

And this is the output from the list:

```
$ cat /tmp/list.txt
dbr:excludeRange({1.2.3.4}) -- prov1
dbr:excludeRange({4.5.6.7}) -- prov1
dbr:excludeRange({7.8.9.10}) -- prov1
```

Reference to understand why the complex jinja expression:
[Escaping in jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#escaping)